# JDownloader 2 Tray isn't supported

Tags: java, openjdk, system-tray

I'm new when it comes to using Linux as a whole and I've just switched from Windows to Ubuntu. I've installed JDownloader 2, however, it seems the tray option for JDownloader isn't working. Here's the error message:

```
org.jdownloader.extensions.StartException: Tray isn't supported!
    at org.jdownloader.gui.jdtrayicon.TrayExtension.start(TrayExtension.java:123)
    at org.jdownloader.extensions.AbstractExtension.setEnabled(AbstractExtension.java:79)
    at org.jdownloader.gui.jdtrayicon.TrayConfigPanel$1.onConfigValueModified(TrayConfigPanel.java:65)
    at org.jdownloader.gui.jdtrayicon.TrayConfigPanel$1.onConfigValueModified(TrayConfigPanel.java:61)
    at org.appwork.storage.config.events.ConfigEventSender.fireEvent(ConfigEventSender.java:58)
    at org.appwork.storage.config.events.ConfigEventSender.fireEvent(ConfigEventSender.java:44)
    at org.appwork.utils.event.Eventsender.fireEvent(Eventsender.java:198)
    at org.appwork.storage.config.handler.KeyHandler.fireEvent(KeyHandler.java:210)
    at org.appwork.storage.config.handler.KeyHandler.setValue(KeyHandler.java:748)
    at org.appwork.storage.config.swing.models.ConfigToggleButtonModel$1.run(ConfigToggleButtonModel.java:75)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

I've tried resolving the issue by installing JRE and JDK (OpenJDK) but it hasn't worked out for me. Any ideas on how I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Tray is not natively supported by Gnome 3. The easiest solution is to disable the JD tray altogether: click on the "Setting" top bar item, scroll down the left side panel to "Tray Icon" and uncheck it.